# Android Printing App for Zebra RW420 printer

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth, zebra-printers

I mean to start developing a simple android application for printing labels using zebra RW420 printer. They have SDK for android but I cannot figure out where to start from.

I invision an app with a single screen, it asks for the label or purchase order, how many copies we'd like to print, and a print button. Can someone help me get started. Any help will be appreciated.

How I am a going to search for the printer will the SDK will do it for me ?? or I have to use Androids BluetoothAdapter class ... about the label format do I have to create myself or I can use the existing file in the SDK ??

Can I set the printer to print multiple copies ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info

Comment: @Ovi, we already have one low-traffic tag for Zebra printers, we do not need to divide it further.  Given the fussyness of the blasted things, the more concentrated the knowledge, the better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The SDK provides a bluetooth discovery class. Look at the documentation and the examples. Check out the `BluetoothDiscoverer` class. It provides a method to find all bluetooth devices and notifies you in a handler. There is a Developer Demo which comes with the SDK which has an example of how to do a discovery:

```
    try {
        BluetoothDiscoverer.findPrinters(this, new DiscoveryHandler() {

            public void foundPrinter(DiscoveredPrinter printer) {
                String macAddress = printer.address;
                //I found a printer! I can use the properties of a Discovered printer (address) to make a Bluetooth Connection
            }

            public void discoveryFinished() {
                //Discovery is done
            }

            public void discoveryError(String message) {
                //Error during discovery
            }
        });
    } catch (ConnectionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You have to print from a thread like:

```
new Thread (new Runnable () {
  public void run () {
    enablePrintButton (false);
    Looper.prepare ();
    doConnectionTest ();
    Looper.loop ();
    Looper.myLooper ().quit ();
  }
}).start ();
```

2) Then:

```
private void doConnectionTest () {
    printer = connect ();

    if (printer != null) {
      //print
    } else {
      disconnect ();
    }
  }
```

3) Print method:

```
private void sendTestLabel () {
    try {
      ZebraPrinterLinkOs linkOsPrinter = ZebraPrinterFactory.createLinkOsPrinter (printer);

      PrinterStatus printerStatus =
          (linkOsPrinter != null) ? linkOsPrinter.getCurrentStatus () : printer.getCurrentStatus ();

      if (printerStatus.isReadyToPrint) {
        byte[] configLabel = getConfigLabel ();
        connection.write (configLabel);
        setStatus ("Sending Data", Color.BLUE);
      } else if (printerStatus.isHeadOpen) {
        setStatus ("Printer Head Open", Color.RED);
      } else if (printerStatus.isPaused) {
        setStatus ("Printer is Paused", Color.RED);
      } else if (printerStatus.isPaperOut) {
        setStatus ("Printer Media Out", Color.RED);
      }
      DemoSleeper.sleep (1500);
      if (connection instanceof BluetoothConnection) {
        String friendlyName = ((BluetoothConnection) connection).getFriendlyName ();
        setStatus (friendlyName, Color.MAGENTA);
        DemoSleeper.sleep (500);
      }
    } catch (ConnectionException e) {
      setStatus (e.getMessage (), Color.RED);
    } finally {
      disconnect ();
    }
  }
```

**4) Label configuration method:**

```
private byte[] getConfigLabel () {
     byte[] configLabel = null;

     try {
       PrinterLanguage printerLanguage = printer.getPrinterControlLanguage ();
       SGD.SET ("device.languages", "zpl", connection);

       if (printerLanguage == PrinterLanguage.ZPL) {
         configLabel = "^XA^FO17,16^GB379,371,8^FS^FT65,255^A0N,135,134^FDTEST^FS^XZ".getBytes();
       } else if (printerLanguage == PrinterLanguage.CPCL) {

         String msg = setPopratnica ();

         msg = format (msg);

         configLabel = msg.getBytes ("windows-1250");
       }
     } catch (Exception e) {
     }
     return configLabel;
   }
```

**5) Connect method:**

```
public ZebraPrinter connect () {
     setStatus ("Connecting...", Color.YELLOW);
     connection = null;
     connection = new BluetoothConnection (getBluetoothAddressKey ());
    try {
       connection.open ();
       setStatus ("Connected", Color.GREEN);
         } catch (ConnectionException e) {
           setStatus ("Comm Error! Disconnecting", Color.RED);
           DemoSleeper.sleep (1000);
           disconnect ();
         }

         ZebraPrinter printer = null;

         if (connection.isConnected ()) {
           try {
             printer = ZebraPrinterFactory.getInstance (connection);
             setStatus ("Determining Printer Language", Color.YELLOW);
             String pl = SGD.GET ("device.languages", connection);
             setStatus ("Printer Language " + pl, Color.BLUE);
          } catch (ConnectionException e) {
             setStatus ("Unknown Printer Language", Color.RED);
             printer = null;
             DemoSleeper.sleep (1000);
             disconnect ();
           } catch (ZebraPrinterLanguageUnknownException e) {
             setStatus ("Unknown Printer Language", Color.RED);
             printer = null;
             DemoSleeper.sleep (1000);
             disconnect ();
           }
         }
         return printer;
}
```

**6) Disconect method:**

```
public void disconnect () {
    try {
      setStatus ("Disconnecting", Color.RED);
      if (connection != null) {
        connection.close ();
      }
      setStatus ("Not Connected", Color.RED);
    } catch (ConnectionException e) {
      setStatus ("COMM Error! Disconnected", Color.RED);
    } finally {
      enablePrintButton (true);
    }
  }
```

Plus you have to have a sleeper class :

```
public class DemoSleeper {
    private DemoSleeper () {
    }

    public static void sleep(int ms) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it working for you? I want to print pdf in my qln420 zebra model, have purchased virtual pdf as well as per their suggestion.